# Controller not found i think to param types being incorrect for MVC from AJAX Post

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

From my experience when a ajax post cannot find a controller, and you feel everything lines up correctly, it is either posting to a GET attribute, or vice versa, or the way json is parsing the data.

That being said, i am trying to post to my controller that contains a string parameter, and a List. It is stating it cannot find the controller. Below is the javascript and c# controller i am using.

Javascript:

```
//here the models are being placed into collection from a kendo grid
 grid.table.find("tbody").each(function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var model = grid.dataItem(row);
        models.push(model);
    })

$.ajax({
        url: "/CheckoutHome/SaveCartByName",
        data: JSON.stringify({ cartName: _cartNameTarget, checkoutCartVMs: models }),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }).done(function () {
        $batchId.val('');
        grid.dataSource.read();         
    })
       .fail(function (failure) {
           tamAlert(failure.statusText);
           $batchId.val('');
       });
```

C# controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveCartByName(string cartName, List<CheckOutCartVm> checkoutCartVMs)
    {

      ... code removed due to public posting
     }
```

Comment: have you tried making the action result a jsonresult instead?

Comment: No not yet, but i have been using a ActionResult for all other ones. I am pretty sure it is due to how i am parsing the params.

Comment: Parsing params and using this method has worked for my, but not when i have a string and List<t> as my params. So i am wondering if JSON.Stringify() is not handling it correctly? It should be due to how it works, but not sure.

Comment: Dang it. I am an idiot. My controller name has extra value to it. {Checkout/} not{checkoutHome}.  Stupid mistake and sorry everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The controller value or name was a typo.  {Checkout/} not{checkoutHome}